# Java UI - doesn't create and populate table

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am trying to pull data from a table in a mysql database and populate the results in a JTable.  There are currently 3 tabs in the UI, the first two being input screens, which work fine.  The 3rd tab, I am trying to run a query (after button is pushed) and display the results in a JTable.  I am getting no error messages, but the screen does not display the table.  Below is my code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Note, user name and password have been replaced with generic.  The query has also been simplified until I can get it to work.  The system.out.print was just to check and see if it was pulling any data.

```
  private void salePropertyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
     String sSelectQuery = "";
    Statement statement=null;
    Connection conn = null;
    //PreparedStatement pStatement =null;
    JPanel panel= spPanel;

    TableColumn column;
    JTable spTable = jTable1;
    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();
    spTable = new JTable(data,columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(spTable);
    panel.add(scrollPane);

    try {
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String myURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/realestate?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(myURL,"root","jul1664bd");

    /*Storing SQL statement*/
    sSelectQuery ="SELECT propertyID, propertyPrice FROM property";


    statement = conn.createStatement();
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sSelectQuery) //executes the query
        ) {
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for(int i = 1; i<=columns; i++){
                columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }

            while (rs.next()){
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++){
                    row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }
                data.addElement(row);
                System.out.println(data);
            }   
            rs.close();


    for (int i=0; i<spTable.getColumnCount(); i++){
        column=spTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        //column.setMaxWidth(250);

    }


        }


     statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("An exception ocurred");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(realEstateUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Query Complete");
}                                                               

/**
```

Comment: What is the layout of `spPanel`?

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to add the JTable after the UI is visible. For the addition to take affect you must call `revalidate` followed by `repaint`. As an alternative, add your `JTable` upon UI construction (before it is visible) and populate the model of the `JTable` in `salePropertyActionPerformed`

Comment: Original Poster: And if this answer doesn't help, then you'll need to improve your question by creating and posting a valid [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I am using NetBeans to create the Form UI.  I added jTable1 to the tabbed panel and made some changes to the code.  I've updated the code above, but still getting the same results.

Comment: @SelliS Did you the recommendation in my answer? Doesn't look so in the updated code

Comment: Yes, I did just recommend your answer, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: `I've updated the code above,` Neither recommendation seems to be in the current code

Comment: *"I've updated the code above"* It's not an MCVE as suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels ..